# Anaconda is not activated

Tags: python, conda

I recently installed anaconda on my laptop after it got reset. When I installed Anaconda according to the website instructions, it ran perfectly the first time. But after I rebooted the system I got this message

```
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation
```

But the method given in the link doesn't work at all. I have installed python 3.7 before but when installing I chose anaconda as my default python.
If anybody has any suggestions, I'm all ears

Comment: _But after I rebooted the system I got this message_ Can you be more specific? Did that message just appear? Where?

Comment: @AMC I mean after I opened the application again, a python.exe window pops up with the above message.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `source activate base` or `anaconda activate base` in the console?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is even the anaconda prompt doesn't open and a gpython.exe opens up with the message which I have mentioned above